# Show that $z$ is prime if $z|xy$ implies $z|x$ or $z|y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $z$ be an integer greater than or equal to $2$. Suppose for all integers $x$ and $y$ that $z|xy$ implies $z|x$ or $z|y$. Show that $z$ is prime.

Comment: I would even plead for using this as *definition* of prime. The usual (prime if it is a positive integer having exactly $2$ divisors) is actually the definition of *irreducible*. In $\mathbb Z$ irreducibles and primes coincide, but that is not true in general. In every ring primes are irreducible, but there are rings in which irreducibles are not all prime.

Answer (score 5):

If $z$ were composite, then $z=xy$ for some $x,y\ge 2$. Now $z$ divides $xy$ but does not divide $x$ or $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by contraposition

$$z \not | x \text{ and } z \not | y \implies z \not | xy \text{  } \forall x,y \in\mathbb{Z} \implies z \in \text{ Primes}$$

Comment: That's not a proof. It's just a contrapositive reformulation of what needs to be proved.

Comment: I've shown such $z$ is irreducible, no?

Comment: I don't see that. Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm not following either how did you proe z is irreducible? 
:\